# Ethereum keystrore file is not created

Tags: go-ethereum, nethereum, c#

Keystore file is not created when I am creating a new Ethereum wallet account using nethereum and UWP. Also the newly created account is not in the private net.

The new account is created using the following code:

```
   var privateKey = txtPassword.Text.ToHexUTF8();
   var account = new Nethereum.Accounts.Account(privateKey);
```

Comment: Did you check this folder for the keystore ? C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\keystore

Comment: @Rangesh I have got public address and password but the file is still missing in the specified folder

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
web3.Personal.NewAccount.SendRequestAsync(password);
```